# Непонятная ошибка во вложенных классах

Tags: java

Изучаю вложенные классы, почему-то ошибка приходит на строке Cat2.Food whiskas = new.kitty Food();
Ошибка:
Error:(43, 32) java:  expected
Error:(43, 39) java: '(' or '[' expected

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем тут проблема

```
public class Cat2 extends Animal2 implements Doing {


    public Cat2(String name, int age) {
        super(name, age);
    }

    @Override
    public void saySmth() {
        System.out.println(getName() + " says meow");
    }

    public void eat() {
            System.out.println(getName() + " eats");
        }

    public void swim() {
        System.out.println(getName() + " swims");
    }

    @Override
    public void sleep() {
        System.out.println("sleeps");
    }

    public class Food {
        private String foodName;

        public String getFoodName() {

            return foodName;
        }

        public void eatFood() {
            System.out.println(" eats " + getFoodName());
        }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cat2 kitty = new Cat2("Kitty", 2);
        Cat2.Food whiskas = new.kitty Food();
        System.out.println(kitty.getName() + whiskas.getFoodName());
        kitty.saySmth();
        kitty.eat();
        kitty.sleep();



    }
}
```

Comment: Так надо почитать текст ошибки, там написано, в чем проблема. Ну или повнимательнее посмотреть на примеры в учебнике  :)

Comment: Добавила текст ошибки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
Cat2.Food whiskas = kitty.new Food();
```

Comment: Спасибо, Алексей! Получилось)